# TCL - Create a regexp which will return the first match in a repeating string

Tags: regex, list, tcl

I'm trying to create a regexp that will capture the first occurrence of a repeating string.

The string is a "list" of RSA certificates , in succession. I am only interested in the first.

The string looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT1..........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT2............
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
```

I've tried variations on the following , but it is returning the full list rather than the first item:

```
set match [regexp {(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*-----END CERTIFICATE-----$).*} $certs matchAll firstCert]
```

Comment: The answers in the duplicate is either "non-greedy match" or "negative character class". The equivalent of the latter in this case is `{(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----[^-]*-----END CERTIFICATE-----)}`. The `[^-]*` expression will match anything that isn't a dash.

Comment: @PeterLewerin That suggestion seems too brittle. If there happens to be a '-' character in some certificate (maybe it's even allowed?) then it will not work as expected.

Comment: @Brandin: yes. I just wanted to show the equivalent in this case. If it is inappropriate then it certainly shouldn't be used. If it is appropriate it's a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the non-greedy `.*?` quantifier.

```
set match [regexp {(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*?-----END CERTIFICATE-----)} \
    $certs matchAll firstCert]
```

References [re_syntax manual page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm%20re_syntax%20manual%20page)